# Server-side datatable ajax when calling function returns 'DataTables warning: table id=tblDataTable - Invalid JSON response.'

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, asp.net-ajax, serverside-datatable

I have a class `DataTableResponse.vb` which has the following structure:

```
Public Class DataTableResponse
     Public draw As Integer
     Public recordsTotal As Integer
     Public recordsFiltered As Integer
     Public data As List(Of Restaurant)
End Class
```

In my aspx page I have my server side datatable getting a list of restaurants from db using a stored procedure (method.GetData taking 5 parameters), and some other datatables properties like ajaxDraw, OffsetValue, PagingSize, SearchBy, sortcolumn, sortDirection from my aspx page selected by user.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Once the document is ready call Bind DataTable
            BindDataTable();
        });

        function BindDataTable() {
            var mytable = $('#tblDataTable').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                //"dataSrc": "",
                "ajax": {
                    url: "adminrestaurants.aspx/GetDataForDataTable", type: "post"
                },
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "data": "Title",
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "colorActive",
                        "render": function (data, type, row) { return "<i class='fa fa-fw fa-circle' style= color:" + data + "></i>" }
                    },
                    {
                        data: null,
                        className: "center",
                        defaultContent: '<a href="" class="edit btn btn-link">Edit</a>'
                    },
                    {
                        data: null,
                        className: "center",
                        defaultContent: '<a href="" class="view btn btn-link">View</a>'
                    },
                    {
                        data: null,
                        className: "center",
                        defaultContent: '<a href="" class="MenuImage btn btn-link"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i></a>'
                    },
                    {
                        data: null,
                        className: "center",
                        defaultContent: '<a href="" class="RestImage btn btn-link"><i class="fa fa-image"></i></a>'
                    },
                    {
                        data: null,
                        className: "center",
                        defaultContent: '<a id="btn-delete" href="" class="delete btn btn-link"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'
                    },
                ],
                'columnDefs': [{
                    'targets': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], /* column index */
                    'orderable': false, /* true or false */
                }],
                rowId: 'Id',

                "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
                    addDiv();
                },

            });
```

Everything was working fine when I was calling a web Service (asmx) class, however I decided to Convert Web Service to private function which is as follows:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetDataForDataTable() As String
    Dim method As New methods
    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Dim columns As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    columns.Add("Title")
    columns.Add("IsActive")
    columns.Add("Edit")
    columns.Add("View")
    columns.Add("RestImages")
    columns.Add("MenuImages")
    columns.Add("delete")
    Dim ajaxDraw As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Form("draw"))
    Dim OffsetValue As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Form("start"))
    Dim PagingSize As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Form("length"))
    Dim searchby As String = context.Request.Form("search[value]")
    Dim sortColumn As String = context.Request.Form("order[0][column]")
    sortColumn = "r." & columns(Convert.ToInt32(sortColumn))
    Dim sortDirection As String = context.Request.Form("order[0][dir]")
    Dim dt As DataTable = method.GetData(sortColumn, sortDirection, OffsetValue, PagingSize, searchby)
    Dim recordTotal As Int32 = 0
    Dim restaurants As List(Of Restaurant) = New List(Of Restaurant)()

    If dt IsNot Nothing Then

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim restaurant As Restaurant = New Restaurant()
            restaurant.Id = If(Convert.IsDBNull(dt.Rows(i)("RID")), Nothing, Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)("RID")))
            restaurant.Title = If(Convert.IsDBNull(dt.Rows(i)("Rtitle")), Nothing, Convert.ToString(dt.Rows(i)("Rtitle")))
            restaurant.IsActive = If(Convert.IsDBNull(dt.Rows(i)("Ractive")), Nothing, Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)("Ractive")))
            restaurant.colorActive = dt.Rows(i)("activeColor")
            restaurants.Add(restaurant)
        Next

        recordTotal = If(dt.Rows.Count > 0, Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(0)("FilterTotalCount")), 0)
    End If

    Dim recordFiltered As Int32 = recordTotal
    Dim objDataTableResponse As DataTableResponse = New DataTableResponse() With {
        .draw = ajaxDraw,
        .recordsFiltered = recordTotal,
        .recordsTotal = recordTotal,
        .data = restaurants
    }

    Return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objDataTableResponse.ToString)
End Function
```

I am having the following error on page load -> '**DataTables warning: table id=tblDataTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/1**'](http://datatables.net/tn/1**%27).

Any help is much appreciated.